# Issue creating new elements in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, addclass, appendto

I'm fairly new to jQuery and am trying to understand some piece of code I just wrote.

I have a simple HTML

```
<body>
    <div id="theDiv">
        <button>This is the div</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

And my script looks like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").on("click",function(){
        $("<div></div>").attr("id","myDiv").appendTo("#theDiv");
        $("<select></select>").addClass("mySelects").appendTo("#myDiv");
    });
    $(".mySelects").on("click",function(){
        console.log("Do some stuff here");
        $('<option value="Text">Text</option>').appendTo(".mySelects")
    });
});
```

So what I want to do is add a new `div` with a `select` and add the `select` to a class. The scpipt above does not work, I'm not sure why, whereas the code below does the trick

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").on("click",function(){
        $("<div></div>").attr("id","myDiv").appendTo("#theDiv");
        $("<select></select>").addClass("mySelects").appendTo("#myDiv");
        $(".mySelects").on("click",function(){
            console.log("Just added the class");
            $('<option value="Text">Text</option>').appendTo(".mySelects")
        });
    });
});
```

I hope some of you jQuery Gurus can explain me what's going on since I don't really know enough to understand it by myself.

Here's the fiddle I've been using http://jsfiddle.net/k1stLsft/2/

Cheers.

Comment: Since `.mySelects` isn't available on DOM load, you need to delegate your `click` event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a couple of alternatives that add select option. The first one is with delegate, like George suggested:

```
   $("body").delegate(".mySelects", "click",function(){
        console.log("Just added the class");
        $('<option value="Text">Text</option>').appendTo(".mySelects")
    });


    $(document).on("click", ".mySelects",function(){
        console.log("Just added the class");
        $('<option value="Text">Text</option>').appendTo(".mySelects")
    });
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jyrkim/k1stLsft/3/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've been struggling to fully grasp the concept of delegation. Just for reference, if anyone stumbles upon here, the jQuery API documentation suggests the use of `.on` on newer versions, so the second example would be more appropriate if you're using the most recent jQuery library.

Answer (score 1):

As a couple people have already said when you're setting the onclick event the element that you want the event on doesn't exist yet. You need to use a jQuery delegate like this.

`$("body").on("click", ".mySelects", function() {...});`

Answer (score 0):

The `<select>` with class `.mySelects` doesn't exist until the button is clicked.